# Dependencies conflict on app release APK, but not debug?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been tinkering with my code for a few days now, and I cannot get Gradle to assemble a signed APK for me (following the error code instructions will result in a successful build, but my Google Calendar API fails).

```
dependencies {
// commented stuff is no longer used or commented for some other reason.
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
//    Dont know whats up with these errors above. ^
//    they seem to work even though they are "incompatible"
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    //exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski.constraint:staggeredanimationgroup:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:transition:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
/*Make sure these are always updated to the newest versions.*/
implementation('com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0') {
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0') {
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
//implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.15.0-rc'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

These are my dependencies from my Gradle files.

Ignore the error on 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0' because its fine; I just can't get my APK to assemble signed; and when it's forced, my Google Calendar code does not return events.

`Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:app:checkReleaseClasspath
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\ClarenceFultonSecondary\app\google-services.json
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:javaPreCompileRelease
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseSources
C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\ClarenceFultonSecondary\app\build.gradle: Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]
C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\ClarenceFultonSecondary\app\build.gradle: Error: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

   Explanation for issues of type "DuplicatePlatformClasses":
   There are a number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of
   the Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones
   provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can lead
   to unexpected crashes.

   To solve this, you need to either find a newer version of the library which
   no longer has this problem, or to repackage the library (and all of its
   dependencies) using something like the jarjar tool, or finally, rewriting
   the code to use different APIs (for example, for http code, consider using
   HttpUrlConnection or a library like okhttp).

2 errors, 0 warnings
:app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.`

> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
>     
>     To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
>     ...
>     android {
>         lintOptions {
>             checkReleaseBuilds false
>             // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>             // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>             abortOnError false
>         }
>     }
>     ...
>   
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   
>   BUILD FAILED in 31s

This is what my lint report says:

> Duplicate Platform Classes
>
> ../../build.gradle: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>
> ../../build.gradle: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following code in app/build.gradle.

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for this solution?

Comment: @zelig74 This would exclude the modules from build dependencies and instead it will use Android libraries for those modules as those packages/classes are now part of Android platform libraries. Thus avoiding conflicts.

Comment: it does not use Android Platform Libraries when using it my bundle was 9MB before and now 15MB..